# Running Batch file with elevated rights through GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, batch-file

I have a shortcut that specifically uses Google Chrome. We have XP and Windows 7 in our environment, and I want to only use one shortcut for both OS. The reason being is that our environment is quite messy, with some users still using logon scripts, while other uses GPO for everything.

Here's the batch file I want to use for computer start up script:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\Google\" (
    mklink /d "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome"
) else (
    mklink /d "C:\Program Files\Google\" "C:\Program Files (x86)"\Google\"
)
```

I created a new GPO > put the script in directory for that Policy `\\domain\SysVol\domain\Policies\{}\Machine\Scripts\Startup` > add the script to `Computer Configuration > Policies > windows Settings > Scripts > Startup > script.bat`. I linked that GPO to the create OU and the computer object is in that OU.

I did a GPResult and I see that the GP was applied, but it didn't create the symlink I'm expecting. Is there an issue with NT Authority\Local System creating folders in C:\? I tried changing the script to just `mkdir C:\temp` and that didn't work either.

Note: The above script works perfectly fine if I run the script under the User Configuration and that user has admin rights.

UPDATE: Tried to do mklink with Powershell without any success either. I pretty sure that you can't run mklink in Start Up script. So instead of using this script, I just use Item Level Targeting under User's preference to copy a different link depending on the OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/q/279077/118258

Comment: @HopelessN00b I put the script under Computer Configuration > Policies > windows Settings > Scripts > Startup, like that link suggest, but didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Computers don't use logon scripts. Computers use startup scripts. Users use logon scripts. Can you clarify what you mean when you say that some computers use logon scripts?

Comment: Have you tried turning the computer off and on again? No seriously, the script won't apply until the computer is shut off and started up again if it is applied in a "Startup" script.

Comment: Add some logging to your script.  Make it log stuff to a file when it starts.  Make it log stuff to a file when it ends.  Perhaps it is running and failing somehow.

Comment: Add some logging,the script does run, seems like mklink doesn't work under the Local System account. Going to do more testing, as I think it's more script related than GP right now.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm having the same issue with mklink during s startup script.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your computer's network connection isn't initialized before Group Policy attempts to run your script. The MSKB article [Windows 7 Clients intermittently fail to apply group policy at startup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2421599) explains behavior where Startup Scripts fail because the network link isn't ready when GP executes the script.  Two solutions are offered:

Via Group Policy:

- Configure the **Startup policy processing wait time** setting in `Computer Configuration > Policies > Admin Templates > System > Group Policy` to a value long enough for the computer to initialize its network connection.  I've used 10 seconds with great success.

Via the Registry:

- Create the DWORD value **GpNetworkStartTimeoutPolicyValue** in the subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and provide a decimal wait time value in seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I looked at that setting and the default for it is 30 seconds. I changed the time to 120 and it still didn't resolve the problem.